# i can't add a color to colors.xml file in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

The color "color_name" in values has no declaration in the base `values` folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow this add colors.xml file.

> app>res>values>colors.xml add color using this tag

```
    <color name="green">#2eaf4d</color>
```

If you don't have color file create using this method

> app>res>values>Right click>New>Value resources file>enter name **colors** then add this color on that *colors.xml* file

```
    <color name="green">#2eaf4d</color>
```

If you already tried both methods you just need to try this universal rule of Android Studio

> Invalidate cache & Restart

> Rebuild Project